# Trouble using namedef and nameref to augment the default \ref command

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, labels

I'm trying to enhance the builtin `\label` and `\ref` commands to let me add some additional text to the number typically associated with a reference.  That is, I want to say

```
\labelprop{prop:example}{Theorem}
```

and then have `\kref{prop:example}` produce "Theorem 3.1" where the 3.1 is the usual reference number.

The reason I have to do this myself is that the usual packages for doing so like `prettyref` are conflicting with the packages my publisher is using.

So I tried the code below---it is supposed to write some definitions that hold the desired text into the `aux` file so they will be defined the next time.

```
\makeatletter
\def\labelprop#1#2{%
   \label{#2}%
   \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\@namedef{my-ref-#2}{#1}}
}
\def\kref#1{%
   \expandafter\ifx\csname my-ref-#1\endcsname\relax%
       \PackageWarning{my}{Command my-ref-#1\space undefined}%
   \else\fi   %
   \@nameuse{my-ref-#1}%
   \ref{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

I've confirmed that definitions are getting written into the `aux` file; e.g.

```
\newlabel{prop:intro}{{1.1}{2}{Results}{theorem.1.1}{}}
\@namedef{my-ref-prop:intro}{Theorem}
```

appears there.  However, the `kref` invocation is complaining that `my-ref-prop:intro` is undefined and producing a blank (ie, just the standard reference number).

What am I doing wrong?  Debugging advice is also welcome.

Below is a MWE exhibiting the behavior I describe.  I added some debugging output.

```
\documentclass[final,leqno,onefignum,onetabnum,oneeqnum]{siamltex1213}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\makeatletter
\def\labelprop#1#2{%
   \label{#2}%
   \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\@namedef{my-ref-#2}{#1}}
   \@namedef{my-ref-#2}{#1}
}
\def\foobartest{foo}
\def\kref#1{%
   \typeout{ref \@nameuse{my-ref-#1}}%
   \expandafter\ifx\csname my-ref-#1\endcsname\relax%
       \PackageWarning{my}{Command my-ref-#1\space undefined}%
   \else\fi   %
   \@nameuse{foobartest}%
   \@nameuse{my-ref-#1}%
   \ref{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{theorem}
%\label{prop:intro}
\labelprop{Theorem}{prop:intro}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

This is a reference to \kref{prop:intro}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If all of the different packages available to do this conflict with those your publisher uses, it may help to know which packages, exactly, generate the conflict since any code you or we write could easily conflict as well, couldn't it?

Comment: The conflict is with hyperref, because my original macros were redefining \label and hyperref wanted to do that too.  My new macros avoid redefining \label or \ref in order to avoid conflicting with anything.  I might be able to find some package that doesn't conflict, but I worry that may be more work than just writing my own macro.  I'll work on a MWE.

Comment: OK, I've editing the question to include an MWE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.aux` file is read in a group, thus you need global definitions, e.g.:

```
\newcommand*{\labelprop}[2]{%
  \@bsphack
  \label{#2}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\@labelpropdef{my-ref-#2}{#1}}%
  \@namedef{my-ref-#2}{#1}%
  \@esphack
}
\newcommand*{\labelpropdef}{%
  \global\@namedef
}
```

**Remarks:**

- I have added comment signs at the line ends to avoid unwanted spaces.
- `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` should surround the definition to keep
  the original spacing behavior of `\label` (a spaces are suppressed after the command, if a space was detected before).